# Filtering/spliting output in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, filtering

I am trying to filter/split the output I get from this code:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties proxyaddresses |
    Where-Object {$_.proxyaddresses -Like "ixi*"} |
    Select sAMAccountName, proxyaddresses
```

Under "proxyaddresses" there's a number that starts with "ixi:+49" and some more information that I do not need. How can I manipulate this code to get only that number and then somehow find a way to filter it even more to get only the last four digits as my output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ProxyAddresses` is an array, so `-Like` will not work on that.
This might help if I understand the question correctly (untested)

```
$re = [regex]'ixi:\+49.*(\d{4})$'
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties ProxyAddresses |
    Where-Object {$_.ProxyAddresses -match $re.toString()} |
    Select-Object SamAccountName, ProxyAddresses,
                  @{Name = 'ixi'; Expression = {$re.Match($_.ProxyAddresses).Groups[1].Value}}
```

Regex details:

```
ixi:         Match the characters “ixi:” literally
\+           Match the character “+” literally
49           Match the characters “49” literally
.            Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *         Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(            Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \d        Match a single digit 0..9
      {4}    Exactly 4 times
)
$            Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
```

Comment: As an aside, because your answer makes it sound like `-like` cannot be used with arrays: `-like`, just like `-match`, _can_ operate on arrays as the LHS, namely by acting as a _filter_: it  returns the matching elements; e.g., `'foo', 'bar', 'baz' -like 'b*'` returns `bar` and `baz`.

Comment: Also, since you're using `.Match()`, at most _one_ proxy address matching the regex will be found among the elements of array `$_.ProxyAddresses` (which is automatically stringified to a single string with a single space between the elements).

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for explaining. Never realized `-like` worked like that on arrays.

Comment: @Theo, could you please tell me what {Groups[1].Value} actually does or mean in the code you wrote?

Comment: @user11124311 It returns the value of the first (and in this case only) capturing group of the regex. It is the part between the brackets: `(\d{4})` where it captures the last 4 digits of the string.You can read about that [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)